# Limit of $\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to calculate the limit: $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}$ where $x\in(0,1]$.

For $t>1$ we can find the following upper bound:

$$\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}\leq t^2 e^{-t}.$$

Using the series representation of $e^{-t}$ we find another upper bound:

$$\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}\leq t^2 e^{-t}\leq t^2 \frac{3!}{t^3}=\frac{3!}{t}.$$

So it follows:

$$0\leq \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}\leq \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{3!}{t}=0\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)t^xe^{-t} =0.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: In my opinion, it is uselessly complicated. You pulled $\frac{3!}{t^3}$ out of which of your hats?

Comment: $\frac{3!}{t^3}$ is from the series representation of $e^{-t}$. How would you show the limit instead?

Comment: Just with elementary asymptotic calculus. The limit is $0$ for any $x$, and results from high school limits.

Comment: I know what you mean and the limit is kind of obvious but this would be no rigorous reasoning. So even if my attempt is uselessly complicated it is not wrong, is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but asymptotic calculus is perfectly rigourous (if you don't do it like some physicists).

Comment: Your way yields the correct answer, but I still don't see how a power series can produce a fraction with denominator $t^3$

Comment: $e^{-t}= \frac{1}{1+\frac{t^1}{1!}+\frac{t^2}{2!}+...}\Rightarrow e^{-t}\leq \frac{1}{\frac{t^3}{3!}}=\frac{3!}{t^3}$

Comment: With this explanation (which supposes $t> 0$), it is  much more convincing. I still prefer asymptotic calculus, as most of the times, it avoids being cluttered by unnecessary details.

Answer (score 2):

If $t\geq 1$, then $$\frac{\ln(t)}{e^t}\leq \left|\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}\right|\leq \frac{t\ln(t)}{e^{t}}.$$

Using Bernoulli L'Hospital gives the wishes result.

Answer (score 2):

By standard limits we have that

$$\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}=\frac{\ln (t)}{t}\cdot\frac{t^{x+1}}{e^t} \to 0\cdot 0 =0$$

indeed eventually $e^t \ge t^{x+2}$ then

- $\frac{t^{x+1}}{e^t} \le \frac{t^{x+1}}{t^{x+2}}=\frac1t \to 0$

and by $t=e^u$

- $\frac{\ln (t)}{t}=\frac{\ln (e^u)}{e^u}=\frac{u}{e^u} \to 0$

Answer (score -1):

You can do that almost instantly with asymptotic calculus:

- $\ln t=_\infty o(t^\alpha)$ for any $\alpha>0$, therefore $t^x\ln t=_\infty t^xo(t)=o(t^{x+1})$,
- also, $t^{x+1}=o(\mathrm e^t)$, and consequently  $\;t^x\ln  t=_\infty o(\mathrm e^t)$,
  which means exactly that
  $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{t^x\ln t}{\mathrm e^t}=0.$$

Comment: I have to admit that I almost don't use asymptotics, not because I dislike "big O"-notation but rather it doesn't facilitate reasoning. In most cases you still have to prove if, for functions $f,g$, it holds $f=\omicron(g)$ (at least from the vantage point of an undergraduate student). Especially $t^{x+1} = \omicron(e^t)$ would require more explanation.

Comment: Any high school student knows that  $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{t^\alpha}{\mathrm e^t}=0$ for any $\alpha$.

Comment: *Bis repetita placent*!

Comment: But how many maniac users are there? aahahahhah....

Comment: @Sebastiano: At least I'm sure you're not one of them :o)

Comment: @Bernard LOL $\ddot\smile$$\ddot\smile$$\ddot\smile$$\ddot\smile$$\ddot\smile$. But if an answer is right why it must be downvoted?